# Maximum length of a collision list in a Java hash table

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hash, hashtable

My professor, when talking about "square probing" (which I assume is double probing) a hash table, says that for the longest allowed chain of collisions we should take the number n=(m-1)/2 where m is the size of the hash array (a large prime number).

I assume it makes the table more efficient to just make it larger when its chains of collisions are greater than half of the size of the array, but is there a good solid reason for this that is sourced somewhere? I can't seem to google or dds it by myself, and my prof made it pretty noticeable that that is the "only correct" way to do so, or at least the most optimal.

Comment: No need to bold random parts of sentences.  Emphasis is generally for words you would be shouting if you were speaking rather than writing.

Comment: I think you should ask your prof to supply some reasoning. Or a reference. My suspicion is that it's a performance consideration: a single hash chain occupying half the space is going to be horribly inefficient. I'd make my limit a whole lot smaller.